# Pandas dataframe - Set boolean column based on groupby count result

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like the following, multi-indexed on filename and number and containing a column with a label name.

```
arr = [['filename1', 1, 'label1'],
       ['filename1', 2, 'label1'],
       ['filename1', 3, 'label2'],
       ['filename2', 1, 'label2'],
       ['filename2', 2, 'label2'],
       ['filename2', 3, 'label1']]

df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=['filename', 'number', 'label']).set_index(['filename', 'number'])
```

All I want to do is to create another boolean column that is `True` if the number of occurrences of `label2` within the same filename is greater or equal to 2.

In this case, the expected output would be:

```
                       label    selected
filename    number  
filename1   1          label1   False  # only 1x label2 in filename1
            2          label1   False
            3          label2   False
filename2   1          label2   True   # 2x label2 in filename2
            2          label2   True
            3          label1   True
```

What I managed so far: I got the list of filenames containing at least 2 times `label2` with the following:

```
selected_filenames = df.loc[df['label'] == 'label2', 'label'].groupby(level=0).count().ge(2)
```

...but I didn't manage to apply the result from `groupby().count().ge()` back to the original dataframe.

I had also a look at [pd.transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) but I don't want to use any transformation function, just broadcast the groupby result as is to all the rows.

Comment: `df['label'].eq('label2').groupby('filename').transform('sum') >= 2`

Comment: Thanks, it works with `groupby(level=0)` as `filename` is the index in this case

Comment: `level=0` certainly works. It should work with `filename` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try `transform` with `join`

```
out = df.join(df.eq('label2')['label'].groupby(level=0).transform('sum').ge(2).to_frame('selected'))
Out[350]: 
                   label  selected
filename  number                  
filename1 1       label1     False
          2       label1     False
          3       label2     False
filename2 1       label2      True
          2       label2      True
          3       label1      True
```

Comment: `df['label'].eq('label2')` would be better than `df.eq('label2')['label']` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Starting from your command, you can just select the rows with the "selected" filenames and assign True (this will broadcast to all rows), then `fillna` the others with False:

```
s = df.loc[df['label'] == 'label2', 'label'].groupby(level=0).count().ge(2)
df.loc[s[s].index, 'selected'] = True
df['selected'] = df['selected'].fillna(False)
```

output:

```
                   label  selected
filename  number                  
filename1 1       label1     False
          2       label1     False
          3       label2     False
filename2 1       label2      True
          2       label2      True
          3       label1      True
```